# Why is my console log response from a POST request different to the one I see in my browser console?

Tags: node.js, post, axios

I have created some auth service in my react app.

It executes in the react App.js constructor like this:

```
if(isAuthenticated()){
        console.log("its true");
    }else{
        console.log("its false");
    }
```

The service is this one

```
import axios from 'axios'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';


export default function isAuthenticated(){
    var accesstoken = Cookies.get('accesstoken');


    axios({ method: 'post', url: 'http://localhost:3003/verify', headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accesstoken}` } })
        .then(function (response) {

            //thats not he response im seeing in network/verify/response, its a different one which always returns the same stuff(wrong) while the one I see in my chrome console is the good one
            console.log(response)

            if(response.data === "OK"){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }


        });
}
```

The problem is that the console.log(response) is logging an unexpected result, it doesnt result the same as my chrome console in the /network/verify(my POST request) tab

Shouldn't it return the same?

Comment: Your `if` statement is reassigning `response.data`. Notice the single `=`, you should always use `===` when checking for equality.

Comment: True, not that its related with my issue, but I missed that, thanks

Comment: You need to add return before axios. You need to either return promise or use async await to return the response

Comment: @AshishModi you are right, thats the issue

Comment: @mouchin777 glad it is fixed. can you mark the answer please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to either return the promise or use async await

```
export default function isAuthenticated(){
    var accesstoken = Cookies.get('accesstoken');


    return axios({ method: 'post', url: 'http://localhost:3003/verify', headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${accesstoken}` } })
        .then(function (response) {

            //thats not he response im seeing in network/verify/response, its a different one which always returns the same stuff(wrong) while the one I see in my chrome console is the good one
            console.log(response)

            if(response.data === "OK"){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }


        });
}
```